# Move the Animation Controls in a Manipulate Slider

Tags: manipulate, animation

Quick formatting question: How can I move the animation controls for a slider from underneath it to say, on the side? For example, I have this:

[image: Slider Bars]

But I would like all of those controls to be on the right side of each slider, instead of underneath the slider.

And actually, if there is a way to just have an input field for the value of each variable, that would great too! I know you can set Appearance -> "Labeled" but this does not allow you to change the value, only observe it.

Thanks!

Comment: About second question take a look to the documentation [Manipulator//Options//AppearanceElements](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulator.html?q=Manipulator&lang=en). The first was asked here before, let me find it.

Comment: Thank you! the link helped, and I got it to work the way I wanted

Comment: `Appearance -> "Labeled"` allows me to change the value -- are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: oh you're right, it does work! but i guess it's less obvious than having the input form there...